# The function will not execute in order to display the data

Tags: mongodb

Goal:
Display the data by executing the function.

Problem:
The code for the function do not work properly.
What part of the code am I missing?

Info:
I'm new in MongoDB

Thank you!

```
db.loadServerScripts();

db.db1.echoFunction2();
```

[image]

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id: "echoFunction2",
     value : function() 
     { 


        db.People.aggregate({
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "Role",
                localField: "RoleId",
                foreignField : "_id",
                as: "Role"
            }
        })         


     }
   }
)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a server-side function.  It is useful for `y = f(x)` type of operations only.   You cannot create "stored procs" like an agg pipeline in your example.
What you can do is create a view:

```
db.createView(
"myView",
"People",
[
 {$lookup: {
                from: "Role",
                localField: "RoleId",
                foreignField : "_id",
                as: "Role"
            }
 }
]
              );
```

and now you can use `myView` like a collection, e.g.

```
db.myView.find();
db.myView.aggregate(yourPipelinehere);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I need to create a similar as stored procedure that contain a lot of code, is it possibly to do it in relation to Mongo DB?

Comment: Answer extended to show how `view` might work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! "yourPipelinehere"   what pipeline should it be? Thank you!

Comment: Well, "whatever pipeline you like."  :-)   FOr example: `db.myView.aggregate([{$match: {Role:"Teacher"}},{$sort: {Name:1}}])`
The idea is that the view behaves just like a collection (with a couple of specific exceptions)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have a reflective question. Is it possibly to apply CRUD for instance create new row and/or delete row from the collection by applying it at inside of the view?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean but views are readonly.   Insert and delete operations cannot occur inside a view.    Views are almost like aggregation "macros".   Go to the docs here for more info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/
Also:  Don't be shy about clicking the vote-up arrow.

Comment: Thank you again for your help!